# Attempting to use IFS, ISNUMBER, SEARCH, LEFT together to evaluate and output specific string of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I'm attempting to use the `IFS`, `ISNUMBER`, `SEARCH`, `LEFT` Excel formulas together in order to evaluate if a cell contains a specific designation in the first two characters of the text string in a specific cell and then output a specific text string into a different cell.

I have tried using various functions to accomplish this and my current code iteration seems close to working but it currently searches the entire cell (seemingly) ignoring my `LEFT("14",2)` argument.

The code 'works' as is but it will also 'work' if there is "14" anywhere in the cell, not just the first two characters of the cell. I have attempted to use the `LEFT()` function to evaluate the first 2 characters in the cell and then if TRUE it would output the "OUTPUT TEXT" but no success thus far.

I am new to nesting formulas in Excel so would appreciate insight as to why my code below isn't working as I intended. If there's a more streamlined way to accomplish this (without using VBA due to security restrictions) I am keen to learn... there's typically a more elegant solution to most things! Thank you for taking a look.

CODE:

`=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ABC",B21)),"Section One",(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DEF",B21))),"Section Two",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GHI",B21)),"Section Three",ISNUMBER((SEARCH(LEFT("14",2),B21))),"OUTPUT TEXT",TRUE,"MANUAL CHECK")`

The cell B21 refers to where the text would be input in this format "14ABC1234".

PROBLEM:

Input of "14ABC1234" resolves as TRUE (as intended) but "10ABC1423" is also picked up as TRUE even with `SEARCH(LEFT("14",2),B21)`.

*Sidenote: I've also used `IFS` and `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` to evaluate if 'ABC'/'DEF'/'GHI' etc are within the cell and this has been working as intended.*

Comment: `ISNUMBER((SEARCH(LEFT("14",2),B21)))` should be `LEFT(B21,2)="14"`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you, this worked. Appreciate your assistance!